# Any presentations or people who'd be worth contacting at Where 2.0?

Tags: discussion

I'm attending Where 2.0 next week on behalf of GIS.SE, and will write up my experiences to share with others here -- perhaps some material worthwhile for the blog idea floating around. **Are there any people or talks** that you'd like to hear about in particular? [The schedule](http://where2conf.com/where2011/public/schedule/grid) includes most of the talks, and I've gone through the attendee directory picking out a few folks who I think would be interested to hear about our community. I'm open to suggestions, and if you're also attending please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

**Of general interest** to the community might be

- **Visualizing Data with Maps**, Nathaniel Vaughn Kelso (The Washington Post) Th 3:30pm.  He claims to show "the best ways to map and visualize data."  I guess we all need to know what they are :-).
- **Geo-Analytics Tutorial**, Peter Skomoroch 2:35pm Tuesday.  "Learn about the newest geo-analytic tools and services."  Who can resist?
- **Living Maps – Making Collective Geographic Information a Reality**, Jack Dangermond (ESRI) 11:10am Wednesday.  A grand scheme "to integrate everything that moves on the planet into a geospatial framework."  Ignore him at your peril: he's still in charge of the 800-pound gorilla.

Of course schedule conflicts might preclude attending these, but thanks for reaching out!

Answer (score 2):

Consider attending [Max Odgen's presentation](http://where2conf.com/where2011/public/schedule/speaker/102079).  Tim O'Reilly presented a [keynote at the Esri Dev Summit](http://www.esri.com/events/devsummit/videos-and-photos/index.html) where he highlighted  [Code For America](http://codeforamerica.org) - regretfully, I didn't have time to attend [their workshop](http://www.esri.com/events/devsummit/agenda/code-for-america.html).

I suspect they do more than just code.  Still, CFA should explicitly mention that it's often a good idea to define at least a few requirements before writing code.

I gotta admit, though, coding is more fun.  There are probably a lot more people volunteering to code than to write requirements.

Maybe CFA coders could direct the City Managers to GIS.SE.  The City Manager's staff would ask questions, the community would answer, then the coder could glean requirements from the resulting threads.

From the "[what we do](http://codeforamerica.org/what-we-do/)":

> Working with city managers, we help to
>   identify projects that can benefit
>   from web-based solutions.